# Linear algebra for graphics in C

Tags: c, graphics, 3d, vector-graphics

I'm developing software that writes to a tiny LCD screen (less than 1" x 1").

I've got all the usual suspects - lines, filled polygons, fonts, etc.

I remember, however, learning how to do fun vector manipulation in linear algebra many moons ago, and creating rotating wireframe objects.

I'd like to do that again, but figured there must be a quick and dirty tutorial and/or simple vector library in C that does all the heavy lifting so I can skip the implementation and go right to the eye candy.

Any pointers?

-Adam

Comment: @ska Aw, no eye-candy for me... ;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I used to use LAPACK++ (http://math.nist.gov/lapack++/), but I see it is now being replaced with TNT (http://math.nist.gov/tnt/)
- For simple rotations you might just rather coding a matrix type and implementing matrix multiplication

Comment: LAPACK & friends are for matrix decompositions, big linear systems, 1000x1000 matrices and up, i.e. number crunching. I would opt for the second choice.